# Python Return int from Enum class

Tags: python, enums

The aim is to use an `Enum` class to allow for predictable input of a definite amount of options.

I expected to get the integers as output, however I get `class.attrib` if I print it.

How can I get the integer instead?

```
from enum import Enum

class Stiffness(Enum):
    FREE = 0
    RIGID = 1
    FLEXIBLE = 2

print(Stiffness.FLEXIBLE)
```

Output: `Stiffness.FLEXIBLE`

Expected output: `2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just print the `value`:

```
print(Stiffness.FLEXIBLE.value)
# 2
```

You can have a look at [the part of the enum documentation about attributes of enum members](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) instead of `Enum`.

This allows to use `Stiffness.FLEXIBLE` interchangeably with the integer 2, for example you can pass it to a function that expects an integer.